# Odoo9 hide fields for simple user

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How hide field **Assigned to** for simple user etc. Project > Task (Assigned to)?

Administrator can see this fields!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you understand the security/groups mechanism of Odoo?

Comment: @CZoellner I0m new in odoo and try hide any part of module etc. field (assigned to) Only administrator can see this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to understand basic concept of security mechanism of Odoo.

Follow below steps:

1. Create security group
2. Give access right to specific Users

For example:

```
<record id="field_invisible_from_others" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Only Admin can see</field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

3. Add group to your field

For example:

```
<field name="field" groups="module_name.field_invisible_from_others">
```

Refer more details of [Security in Odoo.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/security.html)